# Folder Lock in Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: windows-8, password, lock

Is there any way i can password protect or lock folder in ubuntu that can also be opened in windows 8??
I am using windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ecryptfs-utils` to encrypt a folder, and it asks for password under Ubuntu. Not sure about Windows though.

Comment: +1 That's what I was going to say but was going to add that Windows shouldn't be able to read from the ext file system format linux and Ubuntu normally uses. But *if* it *can* be read from windows like described in the question, go for the encryption.

Comment: You can use `ext2fsd` to read ext partitions from Windows.